# c# split string on character when condition is true

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking to use the String.split method in order to split a string on the ':' character. The issue is however that the split is being split on things such as times also. I don't want this to happen. Is there anyway I can specify a predicate which, only when true, the string should be split.

Ideally, I'd only like the strings to be split when the characters either side of the search character are not digits?

---

**Edit:**

Example input:

> Issued: 08/02/1922 Description: Example Description Time: 03:43

Desired output:

> ["Issued", " 08/02/1922 Description", " Example Description Time", " 
>   03:43"]

Comment: please show us and input and the expected output you want

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Sounds like a regex will be the solution to this problem, standard `string.Split` isn't going to cut it for this.

Comment: Indeed regular expressions with groups should help. Add some examples.

Comment: Why dont you split the string first and merge the numbers with the splitted string. For example. 11:10:21 am. T:e:s:t

In this case you can first split the complete string and assign to array

Your splitted string would be 
11;
10;
21 am. T;
e;
s;
t;


Now you can simply merge the numbers.
That will give you 
11:10;
21 am. T;
e;
s;
t;

Comment: Can you not change the time format from HH:MM to something like HH-MM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Regex` for this purpose:

```
 var output = Regex.Split(input,"(?<!\\d\\s*)\\s*:\\s*|\\s*:\\s*(?!\\s*\\d)");
 //Example:
 string input = "a:b:c:12:00:00";
 //Output
 a
 b
 c
 12:00:00
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

For the example given, simply splitting by ": " (comma followed by space) will do the job. Depending on your data format, it may be good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression to find out your string type and then split if it matches your cretirea. Something like below

```
        Regex r = new Regex(".[0-9]:.[0-9]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string s = "00:46";
        Match m = r.Match(s);
        string[] str = !m.Success ? s.Split(':') : null;
```